# Android SHA256 hashing

Tags: php, android, hash, sha256

I have a web application in which I have used this particular code to hash the password

```
$hashed = hash('sha256', $password); 
$randomstring = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)); 
$salt = substr($randomstring, 0, 8); 
$hashed = hash('sha256', $salt . $hashed);
```

I am building android app to the same web app which uses the same database as web app. How do I change this code into android so that I can use it to register and login into the android app which has same things as that of web app. I just need the android version of that particular sha256 hashing part that I used in my web app

Comment: You are not supposed to do hashing on the client side, do it on the server side instead.

Comment: What I had done in my web app was to take the email Id, password  and store it in my database. When the user tries to log in, I will get all the details of the user from the database and then hash the entered password and compare it with the stored hashed password. This is what I want to achieve in Android